# How do I set up a virtualenv on Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtualbox

In a VirtualBox running Ubuntu 20.04.6 on windows 10 I tried to set up a virtualenv on a disk space that is mounted in/from(?) windows (i.e. the space can be accessed from the Ubuntu system as well as windows). I tried:

```
$ python -m venv venv
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'lib' -> '/home/myuser/venv/lib64'


$ virtualenv venv
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/bin/python3' -> '/home/myuser/venv/bin/python'
```

Any idea if it is possible some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **Create a virtual environment in the disk space that is not shared with windows!**